# How to stream STDIO into variables in Elixir?

Tags: stream, stdout, stdin, elixir

I have a Ruby Map/Reduce pipeline where STDIO is cat'ed to the mapper etc.

```sh
cat input.csv | mapper.rb | sort | reducer.rb > output.csv
```

There's a line in mapper.rb which looks something like this:

```rb
ARGF.each do |line|
   (field1, field2, field3) = line.split("\t")
   # etc...
end
```

**How would I do this in Elixir?**

Also, I've read somewhere that [File.stream!](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/File.html#stream!/3) is much faster than [IO.stream](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/IO.html#stream/2). In this particular case, I could eliminate cat and load the file directly if it's much faster that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IO.stream`. `File.stream!` is faster for *files*, don't worry about it when it comes to IO.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip! What would the code look like in Elixir which splits the line into variables?  Thanks!

Comment: That would be `[field1, field2, field3] = String.split(line, "\t")`